# PDO query builder class execute() error SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to make a PDO query builder class but it doesn't work in update function. I get error:

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Can any one tell me how to make it work. thanks

```
class query extends PDO {

private $_statement;
private $_prepare;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(DB_TYPE . ':host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $this->_statement = "";
    $this->_prepare = NULL;
}

function UPDATE($table) {
    $this->_prepare = $this->prepare("UPDATE " . $table);
    $this->_statement = $this->_prepare->queryString;
    return $this;
}

function DATA($data) {
    ksort($data);
    if (strstr($this->_statement, "UPDATE")) {
        $fieldDetails = null;
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $fieldDetails.="$key = :$key, ";
        }
        $fieldDetails = rtrim($fieldDetails, ', ');
        $this->_prepare = $this->prepare($this->_statement . " SET " . $fieldDetails);
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->_prepare->bindValue(":$key", $value);
        }
    }
    $this->_statement = $this->_prepare->queryString;
    return $this;
}

function WHERE($where, $operator = "AND") {
    $condition = null;
    if (is_array($where)) {
        if (count($where) != 0) {
            foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
                $condition.="$key = :$tempK " . $operator . " ";
            }
        }
    }
    $condition = rtrim($condition, $operator . " ");

    $this->_prepare = $this->prepare($this->_statement . " WHERE " . $condition);
    foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
        $this->_prepare->bindValue(":$tempK", $value);
    }
    $this->_statement = $this->_prepare->queryString;
    return $this;
}

function send() {
    return  $this->_prepare->execute();
    }
}
```

this is test function

```
$q = new query();
$q->UPDATE("user")
->DATA(array("email" => "dd"))
->WHERE(array("username"=>"ee"))
->send();
```

Comment: well, as you are building it, you probably know what the problem means by the error. m<>n

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys, I found a solution by myself and would like to share my solution.

this is code updated

```
    class query extends PDO {

private $_statement;
private $_prepare;
private $_values;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(DB_TYPE . ':host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $this->_statement = "";
    $this->_prepare = NULL;
    $this->_values = array();
}

function UPDATE($table) {
    $this->_prepare = $this->prepare("UPDATE " . $table);
    $this->_statement = $this->_prepare->queryString;
    return $this;
}

function DATA($data) {
    ksort($data);
    if (strstr($this->_statement, "UPDATE")) {
        $fieldDetails = null;
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $fieldDetails.="$key = :$key, ";
        }
        $fieldDetails = rtrim($fieldDetails, ', ');
        $this->_prepare = $this->prepare($this->_statement . " SET " . $fieldDetails);
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->_values[":$key"] = $value;
        }
    }
    $this->_statement = $this->_prepare->queryString;
    return $this;
}

function WHERE($where, $operator = "AND") {
    $condition = null;
    if (is_array($where)) {
        if (count($where) != 0) {
            foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
                $condition.="$key = :where$key " . $operator . " ";
            }
        }
    }
    $condition = rtrim($condition, $operator . " ");

    $this->_prepare = $this->prepare($this->_statement . " WHERE " . $condition);
    foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
        $this->_values[":where$key"] = $value;
    }
    $this->_statement = $this->_prepare->queryString;
    return $this;
}

function send() {
    return  $this->_prepare->execute($this->_values);
    }
}
```

I think the problem might be **prepare statement cannot use bindValue() in separate functions**. Also the parameter of execute() allow me to put all bind values into prepare statement. 
Finally, problem solved.